# Is it possible to use multiple paths for PYTHONPATH on Windows?

Tags: python, pythonpath

I have a clean virtual machine with XP SP3 32-bit and ActivePython 2.7.2 32-bit community edition, current dir is "C:\test". I have placed `sitecustomize.py` with "print( 'dir1' )" code indie "C:\test\dir1" and `sitecustomize.py` with "print( 'dir2' )" code indie "C:\test\dir2".

If i set `PYTHONPATH` to `dir1` or `dir2`, corresponding `sitecustomize.py` is executed:

```
C:\test> set PYTHONPATH=C:\test\dir1\
C:\text> python
dir1
>>>exit()
C:\test> set PYTHONPATH=C:\test\dir2\
C:\text> python
dir2
```

But if i add both dirs to pythonpath, only `sitecustomize.py` of **first** dir is executed:

```
C:\test> set PYTHONPATH=C:\test\dir1\;C:\test\dir2\
C:\text> python
dir1
>>>exit()
C:\test> set PYTHONPATH=C:\test\dir2\;C:\test\dir1\
C:\text> python
dir2
```

So is it possible to have multiple dirs in `PYTHONPATH` and multiple `sitecustomize.py` or i'm limited to one? Documentation states that i can have many dirs in `PYTHONPATH`, but it don't say anything about `sitecustomize.py`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can list multiple directories in `PYTHONPATH`.

`sitecustomize` is a module that automatically gets imported when the interpreter starts up. Consequently, if there are several `sitecustomize.py` on your `PYTHONPATH`, only the first one will be loaded.

The process is described in the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/site.html):

> After these path manipulations, an attempt is made to import a module named `sitecustomize`, which can perform arbitrary site-specific customizations. It is typically created by a system administrator in the site-packages directory. If this import fails with an `ImportError` exception, it is silently ignored.

Answer (score 1):

I sometimes do sys.path.append() to add paths